# Этимология слова "неприкаянный"

Tags: этимология

Неприкаянный - это тот, кто не нашел своего места, неустроенный. Но вот интересно, какое отношение к этому слову имеет покаяние?
Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самое прямое. Покается душа — искупит грех —  прибьётся к Добру, Свету, Вере, царство Добра примет её.

Слово каять (в древнем звучании — кайна) изначально понималось как *назначать цену, выкуп за грех*. Вот почему окаянный — это человек, который обязан искупить грех, а покаянный — это тот, кто уже платит цену за свое преступление.
Неприкаянный — это человек, не пришедший к покаянию, не признавшийся в вине; ищет своё место и не находит.

Неприкаянная душа — между злом и добром, между верой и неверием. Между небом и землей. И в Царство Смерти не берут, и на земле нет ему места, это бродячий дух, он всё отрицает, и его отрицают.

Comment: Замечательное объяснение! С удовольствием ставлю плюс.

Comment: Спасибо. Просто я не согласна с значением "мстить". Не могла не ответить

Comment: Пусть даже и нецерковное (хотя откуда Вы это знаете?), объяснение достаточно логичное и правильное, хотя, может, и неполное. 
Ключевое слово - цена, т.е. искупление.

Answer (score 4):

Слово имеет древний корень "наказывать" (каja-). *Покаяние* того же корня, как, собственно, и слово *цена*(вторая палатализация в общеславянском прошла - гласный Е в слове *цена* дифтонгического происхождения). В старославянском КАЯТИ - наказывать, мстить.

Comment: Да! Именно "цена". Т.е. искупление.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не очень понятно значение приставки ПРИ и способ образования слова, именно это  затрудняет понимание слова «неприкаянный». Например, цитата из форума: «Простите, ничего не поняла. Если это какой намек на древнюю форму современного "каяться", то при чем здесь неприкаянность? И почему нет "прикаянного"?
2. Вызывает интерес и следующая точка зрения, также высказанная на форуме:

«Корень «кай» мог быть в родстве с корнем «гой»; древнерусский глагол «гоить» - парный глагол «жить» (известно древнее приветствие «гой еси», букв. – «живи»; «изгой» - «изжитый», лишённый наследства, изгнанный). Таким образом, «неприкаянный» означает «нигде не прижившийся», а «окаянный» – родственник «изгоя», как, впрочем, и предыдущее слово, причём приставка «о» несёт значение приставки «от». «Окаянный» также близко по созвучию с «охаянный», т.е. «обруганный». И таким образом, «каяться» может одновременно означать «ругать себя» (каять-хаять себя) и «оживлять себя» (каять-гоить себя)».

Comment: Слишком  много  предположений.

Comment: Вопрос слишком неоднозначный, вот и решений много.Каяться, раскаяться, покаяться, покаяние - с этими словами всё понятно. Но как и когда образовалось слово "неприкаянный"? Глагол "каяться" имеет изъяснительное значение, а неприкаянный  - это непристроенный, неприсоединенный, переход значений и схема образования неясны. История этого слова, возможно, не так проста. А вдруг они всё-таки родственники с "изгоем" ("изгоить" - выгнать, выжить)?

Answer (score 1):

Каяться - наказывать себя, признаваться в совершенных грехах, чтобы получить прощение.

Неприкаянный - никем не понятый, не принятый, не прощенный. И переносное значение: одинокий, потерянный.

"Качается мерзлый орешник,Стучит на холодном ветру.И я - неприкаянный грешник - Опушкой иду по утру".

Answer (score 0):

> Из не- + при- + -каять, далее от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. каѭ сѩ, каІАти сѩ «каяться», русск. ока́ять «порицать», укр. ка́яти кого́ «упрекать», болг. ка́я се, сербохорв. ка̏jати «(ото)мстить», словенск. kájati «порицать», чешск. kát se «каяться, раскаиваться в ч.-л.», польск. kajać się, в.-луж. kać sо, н.-луж. kajaś sе «каяться». Связано чередованием гласных с цена́, родственно др.-инд. са́уаtē «мстит, наказывает», авест. kāу- «оплатить, каяться», čikауаt̃ «пусть он раскается, накажет, отомстит», kaēnā «наказание, месть», kаʮа- ср. р. «воздаяние, уплата», греч. τίνω, гомер. τί̄νω (*τίνω) «плачу, каюсь», ποινή «покаяние, наказание». Едва ли более вероятно сближение с кто, т. е. первонач. «говорить: как (я мог это сделать)». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Короче, тут все, что сказано [[@Гудвин01](/users/2541/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD01)](/users/2541/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD01) ("каять" - общий морф со значением "успокаивать", "оплачивать") плюс еще немного о родстве.

Неприкаянный - не получивший прощения (искупления) за свои грехи.

//------------------------

Всех с наступающим!!!
Удачи и счастья!

Когда я в следующий раз выберусь сюда - не знаю (должен был исчезнуть еще в середине декабря, но немного отоложилось). Не дайте затроллить ресурс.

Comment: А  версия  Дерзкого  чем  плоха ?  На  общий  морф  он  не  покушается,  рассуждает  о  конкретном  слове. Грамматике  не  противоречит.

Comment: Это Вы с ним разбирайтесь, чем плоха догадка, когда есть вполне доступное и научное объяснение.

Comment: Если считать, что слово образовалось недавно, то оно должно мотивироваться действующим глаголом, иметь определенную схему образования. Глагол "каяться" как-то не очень годится на эту роль. Приставка ПРИ имеет обобщенное значение ПРИБЛИЖЕНИЯ, которое проявляется в различных частных значениях (присоединения, нахождения вблизи и др.). Например: пристроить (= присоединить) - пристроенный - непристроенный - здесь все понятно. А как образовалось "неприкаянный"?

Comment: >Если считать, что слово образовалось недавно  
  
Не надо так считать. Даже если слово неприкаянный - недавнее, что вряд ли, то есть окаянный, каяться - они-то уж точно не вчера образовались.

Answer (score 0):

_Людмила:
"Самое прямое. Покается душа - искупит грех - прибьётся к Добру, Свету,Вере, царство Добра примет её.
Слово каять(в древнем звучании – кайна) изначально понималось как назначать цену, выкуп за грех. Вот почему окаянный – это человек, который обязан искупить грех, а покаянный – это тот, кто уже платит цену за свое преступление. Неприкаянный же человек – это, не пришедший к покаянию, не признавшийся в вине, ищет своё место и не находит."

_Дерзкий Grantum:
"В книге Василия Бондалетова "В.И.Даль и тайные языки в России" впервые опубликованы четыре рукописных словаря Даля 1840-50 гг.
На электронных страницах книги читаем :
Откайся - посторонись, берегись, отойди, откройся
Откаять, откайнуть - отпереть
Перекайнуть - передать
Прикайнуть - привязать
Прикаять - прибрать
Скаевать - вязать"
"Поиск корня в иностранных словарях.
Откаять/прикаять и др. диалектизмы - из северо-западных (псковско-новгородских) народных говоров. Можно предположить у северных словен некое влияние языков из германской группы (?) Посмотрим, что там на Балтике с каем/коем :
Kajen - пристань, sjöman kajplats - матросская койка (швед.)
Kai - пристань, Schlafkoje - койка (нем.)
kaj - койка, причал (дат.) 
køye - койка, причал (норв.)
quay - причал, quayside - пристань (англ.)...
Мне кажется, здесь есть над чем подумать.
Причал, пристань, морская койка типа "гамак" (KAJ/KOJ/QUAY) - - - - - прикаять, откаять, скаевать (КАЙ)"

---

_Я понял приведенные здесь рассуждения так:

Кайна         - Предъявление обвинения и назначение цены откупа за злодеяние.

Окаянный      - Оценённый проступок (или обвинённый человек).

(не)Покаянный - (не)Оплаченный проступок или (не)очищенный человек.

(не)Прикаянный- (не)Признавший вину.

Несогласный с обвинением по убеждению (искренности; чистоте), а не по лжи, не скатывается во Тьму (Сообщество Созидания на основе Страха, т.е. иллюзии отсутствия Любви), но не признанный (напр.из-за опасности прецендента) обвинителями, не принимается ими в Свет (Сообщество Созидания на основе Любви). Со временем неприкаянные или по слабости соскальзывают во Тьму или находят силу (или помощь) для соединения со Светом через смирение в покаянии.

Объяснение по В.И.Далю и по северным словенам и по иностранным примерам  основано на корне слова "кай(я)"~"место"...Добавлю - "кайма"..., а мы обсуждаем корень "каяН"~"наказание", но словообразования сосуществуют рядом из-за удачного косвенного фонетического и смыслового дополнения.

Основа моих размышлений в приведённых всеми уважаемыми собеседниками материалах и в моём интересе к этому слову. В стихотворении Юрия Денисова "Смерть Анны" применена фраза  "...три прикаянных души."

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемые, а что скажете о возможности происхождения от библейского Каина?

Comment: Каин  это  уже  старославянский.  А  как  звучит  это  имя  в  иврите,  древнегреческом,  среднегреческом ?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, каяться - от слова Каин - ругать себя, назвать себя Каином.
Рас-каяться - отойти от Каина, захотеть стать Авелем. 
По-каяться - поругать себя, поназывать себя Каином, поанализировать свои ошибки.
Не-при-каянный - не при Каине еще, ищет себя, еще не Авель, но и не Каин. Не примкнул еще ни к тому, ни к другому лагерю. 
О-каянный - охваченный Каином...

Answer (score 0):

И все же, Каин - символ первого преступления, каяться - признавать себя преступником. Раскаиваться - отказываться от дальнейших преступлений (не повторять). Окаянный - "о каине", "как Каин"- преступник (Ирод окаянный - это Ирод-преступник). Неприкаянный - не при Каине, не виновный, но обвиняемый, потому не находящий себе места.